# Is there a way to use modular css in React TSX?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import {
  container,
  navLinks,
  navLinkItem,
  navLinkText,
  heading,
} from "./Layout.module.css"; //ERROR

const Layout = ({
  pageTitle,
  children,
}: {
  pageTitle: string;
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={container}>
      <title>{pageTitle}</title>
      <nav>
        <ul className={navLinks}>
          <li className={navLinkItem}>
            <Link to="/" className={navLinkText}>
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className={navLinkItem}>
            <Link to="/about" className={navLinkText}>
              About
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1 className={heading}>{pageTitle}</h1>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

I'm making a basic React site with Typescript.
I'm using modular CSS. On the terminal or browser, there's no error. But on VSCode, `"./Layout.module.css"` part has an error.
How to get rid of that? Is it `tsconfig.json` problem or VSCode problem?

[image: error part]

Comment: Try using default import instead. Change to `import styles from "./Layout.module.css"` –

Comment: already tried, but same

Comment: "But on VSCode, "./Layout.module.css" part has an error" — And what does the error message say when you hover the mouse over it or look at the Problems tab?